# How can I print a list of the names of the periodic elements from this class code

Tags: python

I want to print a list(for python) of a one attribute type like the names of the periodic elements

For example how can I print a text like this:

`["Hydrogen", "Helium", "Lithium", "Beryllium", "Boron", "Carbon", ...]`

---

```
class Elements:
    def __init__(self, name, number, symbol, group, family):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.group = group
        self.family = family


hydrogen = Elements("Hydrogen", 1, "H", "Nonmetal", "Alkali Metal")
helium = Elements("Helium", 2, "He", "Nonmetal", "Noble Gas")
lithium = Elements("Lithium", 3, "Li", "Metal", "Alkali Metal")
beryllium = Elements("Beryllium", 4, "Be", "Metal", "Alkali Earth Metal")
boron = Elements("Boron", 5, "B", "Metalloid", "Boron")
carbon = Elements("Carbon", 6, "C", "Nonmetal", "Carbon")
nitrogen = Elements("Nitrogen", 7, "N", "Nonmetal", "Nitrogen")
oxygen = Elements("Oxygen", 8, "O", "Nonmetal", "Oxygen")
fluorine = Elements("Fluorine", 9, "F", "Nonmetal", "Halogen")
neon = Elements("Neon", 10, "Ne", "Nonmetal", "Noble Gas")
sodium = Elements("Sodium", 11, "Na", "Metal", "Alkali Metal")
magnesium = Elements("Magnesium", 12, "Mg", "Metal", "Alkali Earth Metal")
aluminum = Elements("Aluminum", 13, "Al", "Metal", "Boron")
silicon = Elements("Silicon", 14, "Si", "Metalloid", "Carbon")
phosphorus = Elements("Phosphorus", 15, "P", "Nonmetal", "Nitrogen")
sulfur = Elements("Sulfur", 16, "S", "Nonmetal", "Oxygen")
chlorine = Elements("Chlorine", 17, "Cl", "Nonmetal", "Halogen")
argon = Elements("Argon", 18, "Ar", "Nonmetal", "Noble Gas")
potassium = Elements("Potassium", 19, "K", "Metal", "Alkali Metal")
calcium = Elements("Calcium", 20, "Ca", "Metal", "Alkali Earth Metal")
```

Comment: Don't create all these unrelated variables. Put them in a dict or a list, so that you can easily iterate on them.

Comment: Start by creating an 'Element' class (not plural), then create all the items like you did. Then add them all to a list. Then, you could loop through the list and do something like: print(element.name) for each one.

Comment: Since the data is static, this also seems like a good opportunity to put it into JSON. There are lots of tools, especially in Python, for parsing through JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a smarter way to do that:

```
class Elements:
    def __init__(self, name, number, symbol, group, family):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.group = group
        self.family = family


elements = {
    'hydrogen': Elements("Hydrogen", 1, "H", "Nonmetal", "Alkali Metal"),
    'helium': Elements("Helium", 2, "He", "Nonmetal", "Noble Gas"),
    'lithium': Elements("Lithium", 3, "Li", "Metal", "Alkali Metal"),
    'beryllium': Elements("Beryllium", 4, "Be", "Metal", "Alkali Earth Metal"),
    'boron': Elements("Boron", 5, "B", "Metalloid", "Boron"),
    'carbon': Elements("Carbon", 6, "C", "Nonmetal", "Carbon"),
    'nitrogen': Elements("Nitrogen", 7, "N", "Nonmetal", "Nitrogen"),
    'oxygen': Elements("Oxygen", 8, "O", "Nonmetal", "Oxygen"),
    'fluorine': Elements("Fluorine", 9, "F", "Nonmetal", "Halogen"),
    'neon': Elements("Neon", 10, "Ne", "Nonmetal", "Noble Gas"),
    'sodium': Elements("Sodium", 11, "Na", "Metal", "Alkali Metal"),
    'magnesium': Elements("Magnesium", 12, "Mg", "Metal", "Alkali Earth Metal"),
    'aluminum': Elements("Aluminum", 13, "Al", "Metal", "Boron"),
    'silicon': Elements("Silicon", 14, "Si", "Metalloid", "Carbon"),
    'phosphorus': Elements("Phosphorus", 15, "P", "Nonmetal", "Nitrogen"),
    'sulfur': Elements("Sulfur", 16, "S", "Nonmetal", "Oxygen"),
    'chlorine': Elements("Chlorine", 17, "Cl", "Nonmetal", "Halogen"),
    'argon': Elements("Argon", 18, "Ar", "Nonmetal", "Noble Gas"),
    'potassium': Elements("Potassium", 19, "K", "Metal", "Alkali Metal"),
    'calcium': Elements("Calcium", 20, "Ca", "Metal", "Alkali Earth Metal")
}

print( elements.keys() )
print( elements['hydrogen'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Elements:
        def __init__(self, name, number, symbol, group, family):
            self.name = name
            self.number = number
            self.symbol = symbol
            self.group = group
            self.family = family
        
    # Online Python - IDE, Editor, Compiler, Interpreter
    elementlist = []
    hydrogen = Elements("Hydrogen", 1, "H", "Nonmetal", "Alkali Metal")
    elementlist.append(hydrogen)
    helium = Elements("Helium", 2, "He", "Nonmetal", "Noble Gas")
    elementlist.append(helium)
    lithium = Elements("Lithium", 3, "Li", "Metal", "Alkali Metal")
    beryllium = Elements("Beryllium", 4, "Be", "Metal", "Alkali Earth Metal")
    boron = Elements("Boron", 5, "B", "Metalloid", "Boron")
    carbon = Elements("Carbon", 6, "C", "Nonmetal", "Carbon")
    nitrogen = Elements("Nitrogen", 7, "N", "Nonmetal", "Nitrogen")
    oxygen = Elements("Oxygen", 8, "O", "Nonmetal", "Oxygen")
    fluorine = Elements("Fluorine", 9, "F", "Nonmetal", "Halogen")
    neon = Elements("Neon", 10, "Ne", "Nonmetal", "Noble Gas")
    sodium = Elements("Sodium", 11, "Na", "Metal", "Alkali Metal")
    magnesium = Elements("Magnesium", 12, "Mg", "Metal", "Alkali Earth Metal")
    aluminum = Elements("Aluminum", 13, "Al", "Metal", "Boron")
    silicon = Elements("Silicon", 14, "Si", "Metalloid", "Carbon")
    phosphorus = Elements("Phosphorus", 15, "P", "Nonmetal", "Nitrogen")
    sulfur = Elements("Sulfur", 16, "S", "Nonmetal", "Oxygen")
    chlorine = Elements("Chlorine", 17, "Cl", "Nonmetal", "Halogen")
    argon = Elements("Argon", 18, "Ar", "Nonmetal", "Noble Gas")
    potassium = Elements("Potassium", 19, "K", "Metal", "Alkali Metal")
    calcium = Elements("Calcium", 20, "Ca", "Metal", "Alkali Earth Metal")
    elementlist.append(calcium)

    elementnamelist = []
    for element in elementlist:
        elementnamelist.append(element.name)
    print (elementnamelist)
```

I've just added 3 elements to the elementlist but I guess you get the idea.